# Correct way to define the initial value of a form field in Django from a database, when database values may change

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create an interview feedback capture app using Django. The interview feedbacks follow a template. The template would evolve with time. Therefore whenever a new interview feedback template is available, it is updated to the database by an admin user.

Whenever an interviewer opens the app, he should see the latest value of the template available in the database as the initial value of the feedback form.

Currently I am able to provide the initial value of the feedback field using the 'initial' argument of the feedback field.

Below is the code (I am interested in the R1Form):

```
from django import forms
from .models import R1
from .model_templates import template_R1
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget


class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class R1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    interview_date = forms.DateField(widget = DateInput())
    feedback = forms.CharField(widget = CKEditorWidget(), initial = template_R1.objects.all().last().template)

    class Meta:
        model = R1
        fields = ['interview_date', 'interviewers', 'comment', 'recommended_level', 'progress']
```

The problem with this approach if that if the template is updated the form field still shows an earlier snapshot of the template when the django server was started.

Is there any other way the form field would show dynamic values as soon as the template is updated in the database? I believe somehow if the initial value could be passed from the views.py, then this could be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, I found an elegant solution.
I used the **init** method of the form class to initialize the feedback field:

```
class R1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    interview_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    feedback = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
        
    class Meta:
        model = R1
        fields = ['interview_date', 'interviewers', 'feedback', 'comment', 'recommended_level', 'progress']
```

And from the views, I used the get_initial method to pass the initial value of the form as the template value from the database.

```
class R1CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model = R1
    template_name = "interviews/r1/create.html"


    def get_initial(self):
        """Return the initial data to use for forms on this view."""
        return {'feedback': template_R1.objects.all().last().template}
```